# Only one active btn on JS

Tags: javascript, html

Need to make it so that you can select only one active button out of two.
HTML

```
<button class="main__btn">uomo</button>
<button class="main__btn">donna</button>
```

JS

```
'use strict'
const mainBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.main__btn');
mainBtn.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        const target = event.currentTarget;
        if(el.classList.contains('active')) {
            el.classList.remove('active');
        } else {
            el.classList.add('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You could use/style radio buttons instead, so you don't have to deal with the toggle functionality and it will always work regardless of the number of buttons. It may feel hacky but what isn't in CSS land ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using IDs I suggest to simplify the code! it's too many lines for such an easy task

```
 'use strict'
    const mainBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.main__btn');
    const uomo = document.getElementById('uomo');
    const donna = document.getElementById('donna');
    mainBtn.forEach(el => {
        el.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            const target = event.currentTarget;
                console.log(target.id);
            if(target.id=="uomo") {
                donna.classList.remove('active');
                            uomo.classList.add('active');
            } else {
                donna.classList.add('active');
                        uomo.classList.remove('active');
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const buttonOne = document.getElementById('buttonOne');
const buttonTwo = document.getElementById('buttonTwo');

buttonOne.addEventListener('click', makeActive);
buttonTwo.addEventListener('click', makeActive); 
function makeActive(event){
if(!event.target.classList.contains('active')){
buttonOne.classList.toggle('active')
buttonTwo.classList.toggle('active')
}
}
```

```css
.active{
background-color:black;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<button id='buttonOne' class="main__btn active" >uomo</button>
<button id='buttonTwo' class="main__btn">donna</button>
```

You can also do it this way.